# 2 in the Fermi’s Golden Rule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, complex-numbers, fermis-golden-rule

In the derivation of the Fermi's golden rule many authors expand periodic perturbation in this form
$$\hat{V}=\hat{F} e^{-i \omega t}+\hat G e^{i \omega t}$$

However I do not understand the reason. Why not represent it with this form

$$\hat{V}(t)=\hat{V}(0) \cos \omega t$$

(as one author did) and then expand it via Euler's formula?
As a result the $2$ will be in the denominator, not in the numerator.

Comment: It is mostly a matter of taste. Often exponentials are simpler to work with than trig functions. Where the factors of 2 go is just a matter of how you define $\hat{F}$, $\hat{G}$, etc. The top expression also allows the possibility to include a phase shift in the operators $\hat{F}$ and $\hat{G}$, allowing you to have $t=0$ not be the peak of the potential.

Comment: They might want to be more general. There is no interference between the two terms in the first order perturbation approximation.